# Encryption and decryption using multiple different keys

Tags: keys

I want to encrypt files, wich can be decrypted and encrypted by multiple different keys. Is there any algorithm which can accomplish this?

Example (Each user has a different key):

- User 1 encrypts a file with his key
- User 2 decrypts the file, adds information and encrypts it with his key
- User 3 decrypts the file with his key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the similar problem was discussed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/two-different-keys-decrypting-same-content?rq=1). The general approach was to encrypt the file with a random key and then encrypt copies of this key with users' keys.

However, if you'd like really different keys, check @ddddavidee's [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31551).